# Focus Placeholder of Input with Focus

Tags: css, focus, placeholder, pseudo-element

Is there a way to focus the placeholder pseudo-element of an element with focus?

None of the code below seems to work.

```
input:focus > ::placeholder {
  /* code here */
}

input:focus > input::placeholder {
  /* code here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out right before posting, but thought I'd post it anyways in case somebody else is looking for the answer.

```
input:focus::placeholder {
  /* code here */
}
```